# Django Tastypie Captcha

Tags: python, django, captcha, tastypie

In Django tastypie, i wrote a login Api as follow:

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user:
   if user.is_active:
      login(request, user)
      return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': True
            })
   else:
      return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': False,               
            }, HttpForbidden )
else:
   return self.create_response(request, {
         'success': False,
         }, HttpUnauthorized )
```

i want to set **Captcha** for this **Tasypie Api**.

i saw [django-simple-captcha](https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha), but i found that this module used for **Django Forms and Api.**

is there any solution for **using Captcha with Tastypie Api**?!!

**Hint**: i used Angular.js in ClientSide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, i found that it doesn't matter you use Tastypie. for Captcha you can use [django-simple-captcha](https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha).

At first you just need  create a form like this:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    captcha_login = CaptchaField()
```

And then render the template with this object as follow:

```
def index(request):       
    return render(request,
                  'shared/layout.html',
                  {'form': LoginForm()})
```

And finally check captcha in login method:

```
 def login(self, request, **kwargs):

    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

    # Validate Captcha on LoginForm.
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() == False:
        return self.create_response(request, {
               'success': False,
               'error': form.errors,
               'new_captcha_key': CaptchaStore.generate_key(),
               'new_captcha_image': captcha_image_url(CaptchaStore.generate_key()),
               }, HttpBadRequest)
    else:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                    return self.create_response(request, {
                           'success': True
                    })
```

**Note:** the important thing was Angular config in my case, i add this codes for CSRF protecting :)

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($interpolateProvider , $routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; })
```

finished !